# create column in R data frame adding values in several columns above the value in a different column

Tags: r, dataframe, calculated-columns

This is my problem
I have a dataframe like this

```
df=data.frame(v1=c(24,15, 0, 7,36,10), c1=c(22,15,0,0,28,11), v2=c(0,10,0,19,0,0), c2=c(0,7,0,22,0,0), v3=c(54,22,28,55,62,38), c3=c(44,23,22,66,71,44), cut=c(20,35,40,15,40,30))
```

That looks like this

```
  v1 c1 v2 c2 v3 c3 cut
1 24 22  0  0 54 44  20
2 15 15 10  7 22 23  35
3  0  0  0  0 28 22  40
4  7  0 19 22 55 66  15
5 36 28  0  0 62 71  40
6 10 11  0  0 38 44  30
```

I need to create a new column with adds the values of columns v1,v2,v3 (there are more in the real case), but only when they are above the value in the column "cut"

So, in this case the column "sum" would be:

```
sum
78
 0
 0
64
62
38
```

I hope this is not obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
R> df$sum = apply(df[c(grep("v", names(df), value = TRUE), "cut")], 1, function(y) sum(y[y > y["cut"]]) )
R> df
  v1 c1 v2 c2 v3 c3 cut sum
1 24 22  0  0 54 44  20  78
2 15 15 10  7 22 23  35   0
3  0  0  0  0 28 22  40   0
4  7  0 19 22 55 66  15  74
5 36 28  0  0 62 71  40  62
6 10 11  0  0 38 44  30  38
```

Here's a mapply approach

```
R> df$sum = do.call(mapply, c(function(...) { y = c(...); sum(y[y > y["cut"]]) }, df[c(grep("v", names(df), value = TRUE), "cut")]) )
R> df
  v1 c1 v2 c2 v3 c3 cut sum
1 24 22  0  0 54 44  20  78
2 15 15 10  7 22 23  35   0
3  0  0  0  0 28 22  40   0
4  7  0 19 22 55 66  15  74
5 36 28  0  0 62 71  40  62
6 10 11  0  0 38 44  30  38
```

Comment: It's a bad habit to use `apply` on data frames, IMO.

Comment: @HongOoi added an mapply approach. What is your reasoning for not liking `apply` on data frames?

Comment: Because `apply` turns its argument into a matrix. If your df contains character or factor variables, the result will be a character matrix, and probably break whatever function you're trying to apply (although not in this case).

Comment: Beautiful. And well beyond my capabilities, I am afraid. I will stick to the mapply formula, that seems to be the safer bet, although the columns I am using contain only numerical variables.